# sscanf unexpected results

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char buffer[32];
   char c;
   int i;
   printf("input: ");
   fgets(buffer, 32, stdin);
   printf("items filled: %d\n", sscanf("%c%d\n", &c, &i));
   printf("%c%d\n", c, i);
   return 0;
}
```

When typing a character followed by a number "f7", im expecting "f" to go into variable `c`, and "7" to go into variable `i`. For some reason, `sscanf()` fails to fill both, and I'm getting their initial garbage values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual `sscanf()` signature is this :

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

check your signature of `sscanf()` you have used wrong signature

It should be

```
sscanf(buffer,"%c%d\n", &c, &i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not using buffer in the `sscanf()` call, so they're not getting filled.

```
int i;
char c;
char buffer[32];
fgets(buffer, 32, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%c%d", &c, &i)
         ^
      you're missing this part
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `sscanf`.  The correct way to do the parsing you are trying to do is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// ...

char *endptr, buffer[32];
char c;
int i;

// ...

fgets(buffer, 32, stdin);
c = buffer[0];
i = strtol(buffer+1, &endptr, 10);

if (endptr == buffer+1 || (*endptr != '\0' && *endptr != '\n')) {
    puts("invalid input");
    return 1;
} else {
   printf("%c%d\n", c, i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A Major pet peeve of mine : You say correct when I'm sure you mean 'a better'. +1 anyway for a good answer.

Comment: @gbtimmon I actually do mean 'correct' in this case; the `scanf` functions provoke undefined behavior on numeric overflow [C99 7.19.6.2p10], which means it is, in fact, incorrect to use them to convert strings to numbers.

Comment: So you are guaranteeing that no new or better solution will ever be found, that none of these functions will ever be deprecated and in the future that with 100% certainty this fits every possible situation? That's a pretty bold claim.

Comment: @gbtimmon I think that's an awfully high bar for calling something "correct"; don't you think it should be enough for the proposed solution to be the best among all not-incorrect options available *right now*?

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf("%c%d\n", &c, &i)` is never told to look in the buffer for c and i, it looks like you are making this call incorrectly.